# How to get the boundary of a set of points?

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of N-dimensional point D (each point is represented by an N-dimensional coordinate), are there any ways to find a boundary surface that enclose these points?

An example output is here (blue lines are roughly what I need):

[image: example output]

Comment: Look for *convex hull*.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks! But convex envelope may not work sometimes, since what I need is something tighter such that there are no sparse space in the enclosed region.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expexted result? Convex hull seemed a very good option

Comment: Maybe concave hull? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1231

Comment: The easiest to calculate is probably the axis-aligned [hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle).

Comment: @Miki OK, I just added an example output, you may take a look.

Comment: @Miki Yes, concave hull seems great.

Comment: @Miki By the way, is there a high-dimensional version of concave hull?

Comment: actually I don't know, but seems that at least a [3D version](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9410208.pdf) exists

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a kernel density estimation (KDE), which will generate a probability density function. For a fixed value of the density that is low enough, the surface should enclose all the points.